# How can I create a service account associated with a marketplace application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a google app engine marketplace application, with an associated API console in which I've enabled some APIs.  I need to set up a service account so I can use GDrive with my app.

Normally the API console (for a given API project) starts out with a big OAuth2 button, from which I can create a service account.  No such button exists for my marketplace app's API console.

How can I create a service account associated with my marketplace application?

Overall, it appears that the "Authorized Access" section of the API console is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Authorized Access" section of the API console is actually there, it's just not visible.  After enabling GDrive for the existing app and ensuring all API Project settings were properly set up, I made the "Authorized Access" section visible (via CSS tweaking) and attempted to add a service account.  The first time failed (possibly due to some delay in enabling the GDrive API or some other API console setting); a subsequent attempt resulted in a service account being created for the API project.  Success!